# OperationCanceledException on stress test

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-cloud-services

I just made an WebApi (C#, .net 4.5.2) and published it to the web. In order to make sure it working good, I started a to test it.

The REST web-service failed the "stress" test. I sent the service 30+- http requests, each second, and got back this typical error message:

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Same error occurred many times in the log.

When I entered the specific machine, I saw that the CPU is on 100% and the RAM is on 80%. Which mean, the machine gives her best to handle the load.

### Questions

1. According to the StackTrace I provided above, I cannot understand
   where exactly was the problem in my code?
2. My code is scale out automatically (hosted in the cloud). But, new machine created only after 5 minutes (depends on the average CPU > 50%). How should I handle sudden mass of HTTP request? Maybe the server should say: "Hey, try agian in 30 seconds" or something like that? What is the right solution?

Comment: Without knowing what your stress test does this can't be answered. Please show your code.

Comment: Cannot share the whole project... However, the exception above not mentioned my code in his stack-trace.

Comment: Without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) no one is going to be able to help.

Comment: What about question number 2? this question not related to any code.

Comment: Possibly, but that's pretty vague as well. The answer to this entire question is *it depends*. I'm not sure this is going to be a good fit for SO. I think your best bet is more testing. You need to start you stress tests quite low then ramp them up (gradulally while observing the results) and see at exactly what point the performance starts to degrade

Answer (score 3):

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
```

This usually indicates that the client connecting to the service closed the connection before the service could send a response. In terms of api layer this usually means that you have specified a timeout while establishing the http connection, or the library that you are using for making http calls has a default timeout.

You may want to check the iis request logs to see what is going wrong. Since this is happening on a stress test, my guess is your service is running short of threads (Read [this](https://fullsocrates.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/asp-net-threadstuning-thread-parameters-12-2/) for more details) . You may want to consider async model for your request handlers to improve the scalability and utilize threads better. (Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx))